# custom 502 bad gataway for nginx, cannot get it to work, whats wrong?

Tags: nginx, unicorn, custom-errors, 502-error

**Im trying to catch a 502 bad gataway for nginx with unicorn. This error is thrown when unicorn is *not* running. Im trying to use a custom error page instead for when unicorn is not running to no avail.**

What did I miss? according to docs this should be right and I just don't see any errors.

upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/srv/host/shared/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

```
server {

    listen 80 deferred;
    server_name host.com host.com
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

    root /srv/host/public;

    location / {
        try_files /system/maintenance.html $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

    location @unicorn {
        error_page 502 /system/maintenance.html;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://unicorn;
    }

}
```

My nginx error.log shows:

```
 unix:/srv/host/shared/tmp/unicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.117.60.95, server: host.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/srv/host/shared/tmp/unicorn.sock:/", host: "host.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have custom error-pages in nginx. Add something like the following to your config:

```
error_page  502 /path/to/error-pages/502_bad_gateway.html;
```

Comment: Hi Nick, ive updated the orginal question to be more clear, its strange but as above it won't work. Could you confirm there are no errors in this config? it won't get the 502 nor display any errors of the maintenance.html file not found so the 502 rule seems not triggered

Comment: `error_page` should be in your `server` block, not the `location` block.